# Why is selenium find element not working?

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I learning python web automation using selenium but when I trying to add a input for find_element_by_name  it is not working.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe' 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('https://kahoot.it')
codeInput = driver.find_element_by_name('gadmeId')
codeInput = 202206
```

I have downloaded the chromedriver but still it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure that you spelled it "gameId" and not "gadmeId"

Also import send keys:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Then you can send the gameId

```
codeInput = driver.find_element_by_name('gameId')
codeInput.send_keys('202206')
```

Answer (score 0):

To send value to the input tag.

```
codeInput.send_keys('202206')
```

Also

```
driver.find_element_by_name('gameId')
```

is suppose to be gameId.  I would also use a wait after the driver.get() for page loading.

Answer (score 0):

Use `send_keys` to send input to the element, otherwise you are running overwriting the variable:

```
codeInput.send_keys('202206')
```

Your assignment to `codeInput` works fine, still check the name attribute correctly.